# Generate all permutations of cyclic shift of length K in a list of length N efficiently

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation, cyclic

> How can I generate all permutations of cyclic shifts of length k in a list of length n. Here shift is cyclic and right. Notice that:

if K==1 , there's no shift. Hence, no permutation of those 0 shifts.
if K==2 , this is equivalent to swapping the elements. Hence all n! permutations can be generated.

eg. if list is [1 4 2],K=2  (thus from 0 to N-K, loop)

```
P1: [1,4,2] #Original list. No shift.
P2: [4,1,2] #Shift from 0 of [1,4,2]
P3: [4,2,1] #Shift from 1 of [4,1,2] as 0 gives P1
P4: [2,4,1] #Shift from 0 of [4,2,1]  
P5: [2,1,4] #Shift from 1 of [1,4,2] as 0 of P4=P3
P6: [1,2,4] #Shift from 0 of [2,1,4]
```

if K==3, things get interesting as some permutations are left out.

eg. if list=[1,3,4,2],K=3 ( thus from index 0 to 4-3,loop)

```
P1 : [1,3,4,2] #Original list. No shift. 
P2 : [4,1,3,2] #Shift from 0th of [1,3,4,2]  
P3 : [3,4,1,2] #Shift from 0th of [4,1,3,2]  
P4 : [3,2,4,1] #Shift from 1th of [3,4,1,2] as 0th gives P1
P5 : [4,3,2,1] #Shift from 0th of [3,2,4,1] 
P6 : [2,4,3,1] #Shift from 0th of [4,3,2,1] 
P7 : [2,1,4,3] #Shift from 1th of [2,4,3,1] as 0th gives P3
P8 : [4,2,1,3] #Shift from 0th of [2,1,4,3] 
P9 : [1,4,2,3] #Shift from 0th of [4,2,1,3] 
P10: [2,3,1,4] #Shift from 1th of [2,1,4,3] as 0 from P9=P7,1 from P9=P1,1 from P8=P5  
P11: [1,2,3,4] #Shift from 0th of [2,3,1,4] 
P12: [3,1,2,4] #Shift from 0th of [1,2,3,4] 

#Now,all have been generated, as moving further will lead to previously found values.
```

> **Notice,that these permutations are half (12) of what should've been (24).**
>   To, implement this, algorithm, I am currently using backtracking. Here's what I have tried so far (in Python)

```
def get_possible_cyclic(P,N,K,stored_perms): #P is the original list
    from collections import deque  

    if P in stored_perms:
        return    #Backtracking to the previous

    stored_perms.append(P)

    for start in xrange(N-K+1):
        """
        Shifts cannot wrap around. Eg. 1,2,3,4 ,K=3
        Recur for  (1,2,3),4 or 1,(2,3,4) where () denotes the cycle
        """
        l0=P[:start]                    #Get all elements that are before cycle ranges
        l1=deque(P[start:K+start])      #Get the elements we want in cycle
        l1.rotate()                     #Form their cycle
        l2=P[K+start:]                  #Get all elements after cycle ranges

        l=l0+list(l1)+l2                #Form the required list
        get_possible_cyclic(l,N,K,stored_perms)

    for index,i in enumerate(stored_perms):    
        print i,index+1

get_possible_cyclic([1,3,4,2],4,3,[])
get_possible_cyclic([1,4,2],3,2,[])
```

> This produces the output

```
[1, 3, 4, 2] 1
[4, 1, 3, 2] 2
[3, 4, 1, 2] 3
[3, 2, 4, 1] 4
[4, 3, 2, 1] 5
[2, 4, 3, 1] 6
[2, 1, 4, 3] 7
[4, 2, 1, 3] 8
[1, 4, 2, 3] 9
[2, 3, 1, 4] 10
[1, 2, 3, 4] 11
[3, 1 ,2, 4] 12

[1, 4, 2] 1
[4, 1, 2] 2
[4, 2, 1] 3
[2, 4, 1] 4
[2, 1, 4] 5
[1, 2, 4] 6
```

> This is exactly what I want, but a lot lot slower,since here the recursion depth exceeds for N>7. I hope, I have explained myself clearly. Anyone, with any optimizations?

Comment: Try starting with increasing integers: 1,2 then 1,2,3 and lastly  1,2,3,4 - check correct answers by hand, then look for patterns in the result.

Comment: I gather that you're trying to solve the problem [PERSHFTS](https://www.codechef.com/OCT15/problems/PERSHFTS) from an ongoing CodeChef contest. Enumeration will not help you here.

Comment: Haha, Yes I know. That's simple parity check for a permutation and printing its lexicographic index/2. I was just keen on improving my original approach, since I always start from brute and optimize as I go on. Thanks, for your tip though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check

```
if P in stored_perms:
```

gets slower and slower as `stored_perms` grows, because it requires comparing `P` with the elements of `stored_perms` one at a time, until either a copy is found or the end of the list is encountered. Since every permutation will be added to `stored_perms` once, the number of comparisons with `P` is at least quadratic in the number of permutations found, which will generally be either all the possible permutations or half of them, depending on whether k is even or odd (assuming 1 < k < N).

It's a lot more efficient to use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set). Python's set is based on a hash-table, so the membership check is usually O(1) rather than O(N). However, there are a couple of limitations:

1. The elements added to the set need to be [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable), and Python lists are not hashable. Fortunately, tuples are hashable, so a small change fixes the issue.
2. Iterating over a set is unpredictable. In particular, you cannot reliably modify the set while you are iterating over it.

In addition to changing P to a tuple and stored_perms to a set, it's worthwhile considering search based on a workqueue instead of a recursive search. I don't know if it will be any faster, but it avoids any issues with recursion depth.

Putting all that together, I threw the following together:

```
def get_cyclics(p, k):
  found = set()      # set of tuples we have seen so far
  todo = [tuple(p)]  # list of tuples we still need to explore
  n = len(p)
  while todo:
    x = todo.pop()
    for i in range(n - k + 1):
      perm = ( x[:i]                    # Prefix
             + x[i+1:i+k] + x[i:i+1]    # Rotated middle
             + x[i+k:]                  # Suffix
             )
      if perm not in found:
        found.add(perm)
        todo.append(perm)
  for x in found:
    print(x)
```

Comment: @AmanGarg: The solution you are looking for is an algorithm to decide whether a particular permutation can be generated or not. There are more than three million permutations of 10 elements, and the number continues climbing exponentially, so enumerating permutations is definitely not the way to go. Here's a hint: look for permutation parity.